# Create Param similar TFont.Style in class Delphi

Tags: class, delphi, parameters

How can I create this parameter similar TFont.Style in Delphi where I group items

Example:

```
TFont.Style = [fsBold, fsTialic]
TMyTest.Type = [Item1, Item2, Item2]
```

How do I create this in my Delphi class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are *sets*. A set is defined in terms of an *enumeration*. Define an enumeration, and then define a set. For example:

```
type
  TAndreEnum = (Item1, Item2, Item3);
  TAndreEnums = set of TAndreEnum;
```

Now you can define your field or property as type `TAndreEnums`.